# Odd error using strdup in C

Tags: c, malloc, strdup

I'm trying to use the strdup() function in C but I'm getting an odd error involving malloc. My condensed code is:

```
void loadEntity(FILE *inFP, entity_t *ent, char *token) {
char buffer[100] = "buffer";
if (strcmp(token, "name") == 0) {
  if (fscanf(inFP, "%s", buffer) != 1) {

   fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", "Error reading name.");
   exit(1);
   }

  //For testing purposes
  fprintf(stdout, "Buffer: %s", buffer);

  ent -> name = strdup(buffer);
}
}
```

And the result is:

```
hw6: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

Buffer: plane1Aborted (core dumped)

Towards the very end of the result, you can see the result of my fprintf statement (Buffer: plane1), which is exactly as it should be. The first line of my input text is "name plane1". So basically, it's seeing the token name, taking the next word, and then setting ent -> name to this. Seems simple but it's not working. Note that even if I remove the if statements, it has the same result. Also, if I just make it "strdup("String")", I get the same problem.

Comment: are you sure the buffer is large enough to hold the string you want to read ?

Comment: Like I said, the fprintf is printing the buffer and it's coming out just fine. Wouldn't that mean that it is working properly? Also, the string is "plane1" so that should fit.

Comment: yes, I've read it again, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, if I just make it "strdup("String")", I get the same problem.

I think memory is corrupted somewhere else, you should use valgrind or something else to detect memory leaks, and go from there.

Comment: Indeed. If other parts of code have similar careless assumptions, this is quite possible. It's always faster to spend the little bit of time to write safe code, than ending up debugging corrupted memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the buffer is too small and fscanf corrupts memory. Try %99s as a quick test for this.

And never ever write code like this, which allows external data to cause buffer overflow. If you see such code, burn it, burn it with fire! ;-)

Comment: The fprintf is printing the buffer and it's coming out just fine. Wouldn't that mean that the fscanf is working properly? Also, the string is "plane1" so that should fit. I'm not sure what you mean by trying %99s.

Comment: I mean, use fscanf(inFP, "%99s", buffer)

Comment: @Jaghancement: putting a number between the `%` and `s` tells the ~printf-family of functions the maximum number of characters to read into the string, so you can use it to protect yourself from buffer overrun.  As you say though, that can't have been your problem in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Use electric-fence to detect buffer overflow :

```
apt-get install electric-fence

gcc -c -o prog.o prog.c -g
gcc -o prog prog.o -lefence -g

gdb ./prog

run
```

and you'll have the line of the buffer overflow.

So simple !